# Comparing two numbers in symbolic form

Tags: symbolic-computation

How can I compare two numbers in symbolic form? For example, how can I prove, that $ln(2)\times\sqrt5<ln(3)\times\sqrt2$?

Comment: Did you attempt the problem first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use continued fractions to get a good upper bound on $\sqrt{5}$ and a lower bound on $\sqrt{2}$.
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{5}=
2 +\frac{1}{4+\frac{1}{\ddots}} \\
\sqrt{2}=
1 +\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{\ddots}}}
\end{eqnarray*}
So $\sqrt{5}<\frac{161}{72}$ and $\frac{41}{29} < \sqrt{2}$.Now Wolfram alpha says $2^{161 \times 29}=3.23\cdots \times 10^{1405}$ and $3^{41 \times 72}=2.90\cdots \times 10^{1408}$ Then 
\begin{eqnarray*}
2^\sqrt{5}<
2 ^\frac{161}{72} < 3^{\frac{41}{29}}<3^\sqrt{2}
\end{eqnarray*}
Now take natural logarithms.

Comment: Anybody fancy giving me a lesson in latex ? ... gratitude in advance if someone neatens up these equations.

Comment: The lower bound on $\sqrt5$ should be $\frac{7}{5}$ and then it doesn't work.

Comment: @MartinSchmied You are right I had made a clanger in my previous solution.